# Depend jinja2 set statement on saltstack state

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I am using saltstack and I have a use case that I need to depend a jinja2 `set` statement
to a state in saltstack
I am using:

```
{% set var = salt['cmd.run'](ipmitool -I lanplus -H hostip -U username -P password raw 0x0c 0x02 0x01 
0x05 0x00 0x00) %}
```

the problem is that i dont have ipmitool installed on the system so im using

```
install-ipmi:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: ipmitool
```

the problem is that the set statement is being processed while the sls file rendered which is before the states, so i get `/usr/bin/ipmitool does not exists`.

Also tried the built it salt module to run ipmi commands,
`ipmi.raw_command`
but i get no data returned even when the exit code is 0.

I assume depending a set statement on state isnt possible so anyone has alternative way to do so or any suggetsion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Jinja is processed first to generate the states, then the states are executed. There's no way to have them the other way around.

The correct solution depends on why you're trying to set this variable in the first place.

If it's to simply pass to another state, then a [slot](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/slots/) may be what you need.

```yaml
install-ipmi:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: ipmitool

something else:
  some.state:
    - value: '__slot__:salt:cmd.run(ipmitool -I lanplus -H hostip -U username -P password raw 0x0c 0x02 0x01 0x05 0x00 0x00)'
    - require:
      - pkg: ipmitool
```

Alternatively, a custom state or module, or just running it twice.

---

Aside: Salt already has built-in IPMI support, that does not require installing that tool:

- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.ipmi.html
- https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.ipmi.html